# RSelenium: How to click on checkbox

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I was wondering whether someone could help me out with the following issue: For a research project, I have to collect addresses of bank branches. On this [site](https://sberbankbl.ba/point/pointlist), the locations include ATMs (Bankomati) as well as branches. Deselecting the checkbox on ATMs provides the addresses I am interested in.

With the code below, I am able to load the page and check the status of the checkbox (`isElementSelected`). However, I can't change the checkbox (using `clickElement`). I think I use the correct DOM "id", since the result of `isElementSelected` changes when I manually click on the checkbox.

In short, how can I click on the checkbox via RSelenium?
Below my code. Many thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
    
link_to_address <- "https://sberbankbl.ba/point/pointlist"


library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4541L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(link_to_address)
Sys.sleep(5) 

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', 
                             value = 'atmCheckbox')

webElem$isElementSelected()
webElem$clickElement()
```

Comment: You can remove the checkbox with `remDr$executeScript('$("#atmCheckbox").parent().removeClass("checked");')`, but it doesn't trigger the event.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong many thx. What is surprising - when I use $isElementSelected() the result remains unchanged (true), even after having removed the check with the command you suggested (the check is not visible any longer).

Comment: indeed, that was strange to me, too.  In fact, if you use the web console to look at the page source, the `checked` status of that checkbox never changes when you add or remove the checkbox.